# Android Market return CANCELED code for all purchase request?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I build an "in-app purchase" application. I don't know why Android Market return CANCELED code for all purchase request? Purchase request is sent ok, receive data ok, but Android Market always return CANCELED. Last two days, it work fine :(

In my project, I have two Android device use the same "test account" and one Android Developer account. Anybody can help me?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that In-app billing doesn't support for my country(VietNam). In-app billing is only available for countrys: http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=150324

Read "In-App Billing Availability and Policies" before you want to build an In-app billing application:

http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?answer=1153481